# wx.KeyEvent and non-QWERTY keyboards

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm working with wxPython, the Python bridge to wxWidgets, so I guess a wxWidgets user could reply.  I'm playing with the `KeyEvent` class and since I'm testing my code on other platforms and other keyboards, I've made an incredible (to me) discovery: other keyboard layouts don't seem to be very well supported.

Here's what I mean: if you run the demo (`KeyEvents.py` in my case) and press on random letters, with a QWERTY keyboard, everything works.  Switch to another layout, things still work... somewhat.  Right now I have an AZERTY keyboard mostly used in France, so when I press the a key (which is on the English position of the q) a 'a' is reported.  So far so good.  But if I press a é (a key which is on the English 2 key), a 2 is reported.  Reading the documentation didn't exactly help me to figure out what is going on.  Is that a kind of mistake no one has noticed since wx is out?  I would guess and hope not, but better late than never I guess.

To be more technical still, the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events have this problem.  I have an AZERTY kleyboard, I press on the 2 key, and a 2 is reported, whereas a é is written on screen.  Admittedly, the `Char` event does report a é, but, if I understood correctly, a `Char` event is not triggered in any context a `KeyDown` event is triggered.  Perhaps I missed something here and perhaps that's the solution for me and international users.

Thanks in advance for your reply,

Comment: You say that a character is "reported".  How?  Are you using the GetUnicodeKey method on the wxKeyEvent instance delivered to the event handler?  If not, you should try that.

Comment: Perhaps it's the way you have descibed the problem but I don't see what your issue is. You say the 2 key is reported, well essentially that is nothing more than a label for the key, it could be called "dog biscuit". The `event.GetUnicodeKey()` will report the visible character returned. You also have the `GetRawKeyCode` if that doesn't hack it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Char event is not triggered in any context a KeyDown event is
> triggered.

False.

Due to each country has its own keyboard layout, wxWidgets sends two events when a key is pressed: One (key event) is the somewhat hardware code for that key; the other (char event) is the "translated" code, normally a Unicode point, but an ASCII code if you disabled Unicode support.

Keyevent is useful if you just want to do something on key-down or key-up events. If working with chars, then use only char event.

wxWidgets docs about wxKeyEvent at https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_key_event.html

Comment: Ha, that clarifies things.  I was confused when I tried to process the doc, seemed odd this hadn't come up, so obviously I was missing something :D . Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Um. Actually. If keydown is consumed the charhook won't trigger. You actually need to pass on the keydown event to allow charhook to kick off.

Comment: @Tatarize Calling `event.skip()` on the key-event handler will not consume the event, but let it go in the chain-event system to allow other handler to process this event.

Comment: "By default, if this event is handled, i.e. the handler doesn’t call wx.Event.Skip , neither wxEVT_KEY_DOWN nor wxEVT_CHAR events will be generated (although wxEVT_KEY_UP still will be), i.e. it replaces the normal key events. However by calling the special DoAllowNextEvent method you can handle wxEVT_CHAR_HOOK and still allow normal events generation. "

Comment: @Tatarize That cite taken from [wxWidgets key event docs](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_key_event.html) refers to `wxEVT_CHAR_HOOK`, and also tells: *It is also generated before any other key events*. So, consuming  a key-down event can't prevent  wxEVT_CHAR_HOOK to be fired and processed.